# Counting positions in a list, haskell

Tags: haskell

-- Write a function that returns a list position index positions

-- of a given element in a list element. For example:

-- I: Positions 4 [1,4,3,7,4,2]

-- O: [2,5]

```
pos element list = func element list 0
func :: [a] -> [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
func  _ [_] _ = []
func element (x:xs) cont | x==element = cont:func element xs cont+1
                         | otherwise = func element xs cont+1
```

throw this error:

```
- Type error in application
*** Expression     : x == element
*** Term           : x
*** Type           : a
*** Does not match : [a]
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

Comment: your element variable has the type `[a]` while x has the type `a`, so they cannot be compared.

Comment: The first parameter is not an array.

Comment: pls don't downvote aggresively on new users questions like this, without any comment - thank you

Comment: it's not homework, i'm practicing for a test  and i just want to know what i was doing wrong ... i'm pretty new with this language ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok think about what you need here.

As @bheklilr said your type is wrong.
Based on your sample:

```
positions 4 [1,4,3,7,4,2] 
>> [2,5]
```

I too would guess that you need something like this:

```
positions :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
```

Here `a` is your element-type and as you want to check for equality it has to be an instance of the `Eq` class.

Next you obviously want the element to compare with (has type `a` of course) and then you give a list of `a`s and the function should print out the indizes where the first given value can be found in the list (indizes begins at 1 obvious).

The idea is to first `zip` your element-list with `[1..]` so you get your indizes with you and then do the usual *didive at imepra* recursive algorithm with lists.

```
positions :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions a xs = indexed a (zip xs [1..])
    where indexed _ [] = []
          indexed a ((x,i):xs)
            | x == a = i:indexed a xs
            | otherwise = indexed a xs
```

this uses an inner function `indexed` that will handle the *indexed* list (in your example `[(1,1),(4,2),(3,3),(7,4),(4,5),(2,6)]` - the second one is the index (see the zip))

Start with the easy case: an empty list of elements - there you obviously cannot find your element at all (no matter what element) so return the empty list.

If the list is not empty, pattern match the first element - together with it's index `(x,i)` and the rest of the *indexed*-list `xs`.

No matter what, you will need the result for `xs` so get it by a recursive call to `indexed`.

If `x` is equal to the element you are looking for `a` prepend the index `i` to the recursiv calculated result if not just returns it.

Done!

Here is your example:

```
*Main> positions 4 [1,4,3,7,4,2]
[2,5]
```

If you don't see the trick with the `zip` (this one is very often used in Haskell but you have to see it first) try to come up with another inner function (*hint:* maybe you can pass the index around as a parameter) ... I think this might be a good excercise now that I gave you one solution.

I hope this helps - have **fun**.

Comment: positions a xs = [fst x | x <- zip [1..] xs, snd x == a]

Comment: positions a xs = [ i | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, x == a]

Comment: @karakfa very nice - why don't you make an answer out of it where you explain the comprehensions a bit and what the differences are? But based on the question I think the task was to excercise the basic recursion algorithms around lists - this one looks more like from a pyhton class :D

Comment: Thanks! i really need to practice, thanks for explaining me that :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the fact that you're comparing `x` and `element`.  In your type signature, you've stated that `element` has the type `[a]`, while `(x:xs)` has the type `[a]` implying that `x` has the type `a`.  Both arguments to `==` must have the same type.  Either you need to do something like `[x] == element` or you need to change your type signature to make `elements` have type `a`.

---

Aside from that your code is very confusing.  From what I can tell from your description, `pos` should have the type `Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]`, but the definition you provided does not match that type at all.  If you're having difficulty getting started with Haskell's syntax and type system, I would recommend checking out [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), which has a very approachable and beginner friendly introduction to the language.